# Segmentation fault on function call?

Tags: c, queue

Leave other errors or inefficiency here and there in the code.
I am a beginner and this is a simple queue using linked list program. I did some debug on gdb and found that there is a segmentation fault at function call create_queue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node*next;
};
typedef struct node node;

struct queue{
    struct node* front;
    struct node* rear;
};

struct queue* q;
void create_queue(struct queue*);
struct queue* insert(struct queue*, int);
struct queue* delete_element(struct queue*);
struct queue* display(struct queue*);
int peek(struct queue*);

int main(){
    int val, choice;
    create_queue(q);
    do{
        printf("\nChoose an operation :\n1. Insert\n2. Delete\n3. Peek\n4. Display\n5. Exit\n->");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
            printf("Enter the element to insert: \n");
            scanf("%d", &val);
            q=insert(q,val);
            break;

            case 2:
            q=delete_element(q);
            break;

            case 3:
            val =peek(q);
            if(val!=-1)
            printf("First number : %d", val);
            break;

            case 4:
            q=display(q);
            break;

            case 5:
            break;

            default:
            printf("Invalid choice !");
            break;
        }
    }while(choice!=5);
    return 0;
}
void create_queue(struct queue *q){
    q->rear= NULL;
    q->front= NULL;
}
struct queue * insert(struct queue *q, int val){
    node * ptr=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->data=val;
    if(q->front == NULL){
        q->front = ptr;
        q->rear = ptr;
        q->front->next= q->rear->next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        q->rear->next = ptr;
        q->rear = ptr;
        q->rear->next = NULL;
    }
    return q;
}
struct queue * display(struct queue *q){
    node * ptr;
    ptr = q->front;
    if(ptr == NULL){
        printf("queue is empty !");
    }
    else {
        printf("\n");
        while(ptr!=q->rear){
            printf("%d \t ", ptr->data);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        printf("%d \t ", ptr->data);
    }
    return q;
}
struct queue* delete_element(struct queue *q){
    node* ptr;
    ptr = q->front;
    if(q->front==NULL)
    printf("Underflow !");
    else{
        q->front = q->front->next;
        printf("Deleting  %d", ptr->data);
        free(ptr);

    }
    return q;
}
int peek(struct queue *q){
    if(q->front == NULL ){
        printf("queue is empty !");
        return -1;
    }
    else 
    return q->front->data;
}
```

Also is there an easier way to find segmentation faults and fixing them ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with digital signature algorithm (DSA). Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your global variable `struct queue *q` is initialized to NULL, and in `create_queue()` you dereference `q->rear = ..` and `q->front = ...` which cause the segfault.  You could make it `struct queue q` instead and then call it with `create_queue(&q)`.  Make `q` a local variable for good measure, too:

```
int main() {
    int val, choice;
    struct queue q;
    create_queue(&q);
    do{
        printf("\nChoose an operation :\n1. Insert\n2. Delete\n3. Peek\n4. Display\n5. Exit\n->");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the element to insert: \n");
                scanf("%d", &val);
                insert(&q,val);
                break;

            case 2:
                delete_element(&q);
                break;

            case 3:
                val = peek(&q);
                if(val!=-1)
                    printf("First number : %d", val);
                break;

            case 4:
                display(&q);
                break;

            case 5:
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid choice !");
                break;
        }
    }while(choice!=5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Be careful with your formatting like in peek you want to indent that 2nd return statement so you know it's conditionally executed.  Push the separating of ui vs logic further.  This will make your code more useful in other context (have main tell user about "Underflow" instead of the function itself).